# Heroku: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository when doing git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I've spent the day reviewing all the existing solutions suggested on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, and tried them without success, and I'm still stuck with this.
The "heroku keys:add" solution doesn't work for me, so please don't link me back to that one.

I'm on MacOSX Lion. Thanks

Comment: Can think of other solution then clearing existing keys and re-adding correct key to heroku :)   It will be good if u can list the steps you have followed

Comment: I've tried everything : I deleted all the files in my .ssh directory, and I did a "heroku keys:clear", then I regenerated a key with "ssh-keygen -t rsa", then added the key again to heroku with "heroku keys:add". It still produces the same error...

What is maddening, is that when I do a "ssh -v git@heroku.com", it shows that I am correctly authenticated :
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

I just get an error message in the end, saying : "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku no longer needs to use the git protocol & Public/Private encryption keys, instead you can use the following command to use your Heroku API key

`heroku login`

> This command creates (or updates) a ~/.netrc file with your Heroku API key.

Now, any Heroku remote repository can be pushed to via the `https` protocol, rather than the `git` (ssh) protocol.

Check the address of your Heroku repository for your project with:

`git remote -v`

If your git remote address for Heroku starts with `https://git.heroku.com/...` then you are good to push.  If the remote address starts with `git` then you need to update the remote address for Heroku

`git remote set-url heroku https://git.heroku.com/...`

> Check the [Heroku dashboard Settings](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps) tab for your app for the full Git URL for that app

Comment: The address that was parametered in my case was like this : ssh://<my email>@heroku.com/myproject.git/br But your method did work and you saved my day ! I can't understand why Heroku hasn't warned more and didn't provide detailed steps to users. You just can't deprecate methods and let people waste their time like this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already git initialized and heroku toolbet is completely installed , enter this command **$ git remote -v** it will initialize heroku git and you can push to it.

Comment: try $ ssh-add and then login to heroku and push

Comment: I just did that and still get the same error message.

Comment: `git remote -v` only shows you the full path of the remote repositories you have attached to your local repository.  It can be useful to check you have an Heroku remote repository connected, but that is all.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you run the command $ git remote -v , will create a git repo in app_name/.git/logs//refs/remote/heroku , first check whether your git been initialized for heroku or not, even I had the same problem and I've corrected.

Comment: But it was working before. I did over 200 pushes in the past. I don't know why it would suddenly change.